# PyQGIS set Null-values depending to the datatype

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, attribute-table

I am experimenting with [the code snippet from BERA](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/425362/set-null-values-to-0-in-specific-columns-using-pyqgis/425364#425364) and trying to fill zero values in a table according to the data type. Unfortunately without success. The value -1 is always entered

```
#Ersetzt alle Null-Werte in der Datenbank
#BERA https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/425362/set-null-values-to-0-in-specific-columns-using-pyqgis/425364#425364
import time
Start=time.time()
layer = iface.activeLayer() 
#fieldprefix = 'animal' #If you want to include more fields you can do fieldprefix = ('animal','human','somethingelse')
#MyFieldList = [f.name()  for f in layer.fields() if f.name().lower().startswith(fieldprefix)] #List all field starting with animal. You can also list them manually
MyFieldList = [f.name()  for f in layer.fields()] #List all field starting with animal. You can also list them manually
MyIntFields = [f for f in layer.fields() if f.typeName().startswith('Int')]
MyStrFields = [f for f in layer.fields() if f.typeName().startswith('Strin')]
MyRealFields = [f for f in layer.fields() if f.typeName().startswith('Real')]
fieldindexes = {fieldname:layer.fields().indexFromName(fieldname) for fieldname in MyFieldList} #Find their indexes

if MyIntFields:
    attributemap1 = {}
    for f in layer.getFeatures(): #For each feature/row
        rowvalues = [f[fieldname] for fieldname in MyFieldList]
        newvalues = [-11 if QVariant(val).isNull() else val for val in rowvalues]
        attributemap1[f.id()] = {fieldindexes[fieldname]:val for fieldname,val in zip(MyFieldList, newvalues)}
    layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(attributemap1)

if MyRealFields:
    attributemap2 = {}
    for f in layer.getFeatures(): #For each feature/row
        rowvalues = [f[fieldname] for fieldname in MyFieldList]
        newvalues = [-2 if QVariant(val).isNull() else val for val in rowvalues]
        attributemap2[f.id()] = {fieldindexes[fieldname]:val for fieldname,val in zip(MyFieldList, newvalues)}
    layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(attributemap2)

if MyStrFields:
    attributemap3 = {}
    for f in layer.getFeatures(): #For each feature/row
        rowvalues = [f[fieldname] for fieldname in MyFieldList]
        newvalues = ['??' if QVariant(val).isNull() else val for val in rowvalues]
        attributemap3[f.id()] = {fieldindexes[fieldname]:val for fieldname,val in zip(MyFieldList, newvalues)}
    layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(attributemap3)
Ende=time.time()
print(f"Dauer {str(round(Ende-Start,2))} Sek.")
```